# Выводим текст поверх div с изображением

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть `div`, в нем прописан `background-image`. Как используя `:hover` сделать изображение полупрозрачным под текстом и вывести текст который до наведения не видим (с текстом сделал так `color: transparent -> color: black`).

Comment: Код в студию....

Comment: попробуйте использовать псевдо элемент https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Comment: Спасибо за советы, получилось так-же вставкой еще одного  div внутрь с уже нужными параметрами и opacity.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я тебя правильно понял, то самый простой способ такой:

https://jsfiddle.net/pleshevskiy/wv8ehs70/

```
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

div:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover {
   color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

div:hover:before {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

А так скидывай код, если хочешь получить прямой ответ.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('http://www.nature-et-yoga.com/images/banner-accueil.jpg') no-repeat center top;
}
.block:before {
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.block:hover:before,
.block:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text">text</div>
</div>
```